# Pose distorts mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, extrude, surface-deform

I am trying to model a character that can kick high. Initial model looks like [image] after extruding vertices from the hip socket

Now I want to make it kick high, but max. thigh mesh can go without being distorted is [image]. How do I get it to kick high without distorting or messing up the thigh vertices are attached to the hip socket? I want the thigh mesh to look normal.

Like this [image] but vertices are still protruding out from, or attached to hip socket Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try "Shear" tool, press "F3" or "space bar" don't know how you have setup your blender and search for "Shear" or press `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + S` and then chose axis on which you want to rotate the end of cylinder